# Constructing Angular 2 TypeScript HTTP GET to work like Postman

Tags: rest, angular, http, typescript

I am trying to construct an Angular 2 HTTP GET REST call to my Spring backend that works fine with my Postman REST Client. So, I can rule out Spring as my problem.

My Postman successfully carries out a HTTP GET with the following url: http://localhost:8082/cq-webapp/oauth/check_token, with a single param of token={access_token_string}, and a header of 'Accept'='application/json'.

[image]

I am contructing my Angular 2 HTTP GET to do the same thing as my Postman REST call.

```
public checkToken() {

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

const params = new URLSearchParams();
params.append('token', token);

const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: params });

this.http.get('http://localhost:8082/cq-webapp/oauth/check_token', options )
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      alert(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.text());
    }
  );
}
```

But I get a 400 Bad Request when doing this. Anyone see why I am running into a problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: where you specified the token in your code?

Comment: thanks for the response @Aravind. I am retrieving it from local storage and setting it as a param.

Comment: but will you ever set a token in params? What authorization  server expects?

Comment: yes. this works in my Postman and is the expectation of spring security with oauth2. Spring is not the issue. I have ruled that out with this working with Postman.

Comment: may be  const options: RequestOptionsArgs = {params: searchParams;headers: headers}; intead of const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: params }); ?

Comment: it looks like doing a toString() on the urlSearchParams fixed the problem.